# Replace text in column based on multiple searches and replacements using Google Spread Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

In column "A" I have the "text to search".

In column "B" I have the "text to replace with".

In column "C" I would like to display the text of clumn "B", but if it has a text string that is present in any row of column "A", it should be replaced with
the parallel row of column B.

Even if a value of Column A gets replaced with antoher value in column A it should be replaced (the replacement function should go on until each and every occurrence of a word in column "A" is replaced, it can be in 4 levels).

Preferebly I would like this as a simple function without having to use a Spread Sheet Script.

**Here is a Google Spread Sheet example that shows what I want to achieve:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kS9Mm_OOv1kanG8Y3-uW-u3yQEHJPbCVT1V5HB7LhOw/pubhtml

As you can see I need to do multiple loops before I get what I want. I would like a function for all levels and for all rows in the document automaticly since I will add multiple rows.

**Cell D2**

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(**B2:B**;$A2;$B2);$A3;$B3);$A4;$B4);$A5;$B5);$A6;$B6);$A7;$B7);$A8;$B8);$A9;$B9);$A10;$B10);$A11;$B11);$A12;$B12);$A13;$B13))`

**Cell E2**

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(**D2:D**;$A2;$B2);$A3;$B3);$A4;$B4);$A5;$B5);$A6;$B6);$A7;$B7);$A8;$B8);$A9;$B9);$A10;$B10);$A11;$B11);$A12;$B12);$A13;$B13))`

**Cell F2**

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(**E2:E**;$A2;$B2);$A3;$B3);$A4;$B4);$A5;$B5);$A6;$B6);$A7;$B7);$A8;$B8);$A9;$B9);$A10;$B10);$A11;$B11);$A12;$B12);$A13;$B13))`

and so on...

Comment: my example only works in one level.

Comment: I see that you have posted this question in freelancer.com as well :D

Comment: Also just to confirm, you want this to work on Google Spreadhsheet and not Excel?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I want it to be a formula, not a google script. It's enough if it works in Gooogle Spreadsheet, but it would be very nice if it also worked in Excel. Actually the answer from @Jeeped is very close to what I want. I just can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you bring in QUERY and limit to a single returned value (with no header) then you can MATCH. IFERROR takes care of no match.

```
=index(B:B, iferror(match(QUERY(A:A,"select A where '" & B2 & "' contains A limit 1"), A:A, 0), row()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with an example. In your example I would for example want "C3" to be "xyqwertz".

Comment: OK, I saw your example. The answer is the same, perhaps marginally more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure out how this could be used to accomplich it. Interested to show me how?